# Getting cells by coordinate

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
            // I wish
            echo $cellIterator->getCell("A3"); // row: $row, cell: A3
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a similar method which named `getCell` above or well-writed PHPExcel documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the `$row` information from RowIterator, you can just easily call:

```
$rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex ();
$cell = $sheet->getCell('A' . $rowIndex);
echo $cell->getCalculatedValue();
```

The complete code would be:

```
foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row){
    $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();

    $cell = $worksheet->getCell('A' . $rowIndex);
    echo $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    $cell = $worksheet->getCell('B' . $rowIndex);
    echo $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
```

Comment: It's very good but hard to implement. I need just a method that gets cells value. Because I have columns A to R. That means I have to write two line for every column in a row.

Comment: why don't you just iterate the cell?

Comment: Because I don't need some of columns. I can ignore the columns but it's not efficient.

Comment: well, this is the only way (if you don't want to iterate). Or, you can iterate it with some sort of whitelisting fields

Answer (score 9):

This is what I needed:

```
function coordinates($x,$y){
 return PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($x).$y;
}
```

implementation:

```
coordinates(5,7); //returns "E7"
```

Though one could also do this for A-Z columns:

```
function toNumber($dest)
{
    if ($dest)
        return ord(strtolower($dest)) - 96;
    else
        return 0;
}

function lCoordinates($x,$y){
 $x = $toNumber($x);
 return PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($x).$y;
}
```

implementation:

```
lCoordinates('E',7); //returns "E7"
```

Comment: What I wanted was the actual value from the cell nothing more you can view the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22566639/1815624)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterate all the Cells in a row, when not use the rangeToArray() method for the row, and then use array_intersect_key() method to filter only the columns that you want:

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();

$columns = array_flip(array('A','C','E'));
foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
{
    $range = 'A'.$row->getRowIndex().':'.$highestColumn.$row->getRowIndex();
    $rowData = $worksheet->rangeToArray( $range, 
                                         NULL, 
                                         TRUE,
                                         TRUE,
                                         TRUE);
    $rowData = array_intersect_key($rowData[$row->getRowIndex()],$columns);
    //  do what you want with the row data
}
```

**EDIT**

The latest SVN code introduces a number of new methods to th iterators, including the ability to work with ranges, or set the pointer to specific rows and columns