# PHPExcel how to get value by cells cross reference value(not by column/row reference but by value)

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I want to fetch the value by cell Cross Reference
Please see the attachment,
For eg: I want to fetch the value "15" by the cross reference "3.00" and "5.00"
User inputs 2 values 3.00 and 5.00 in  a input field, I need to cross refer the Excel file based on the Column value "5.00" and Row Value "3.00" so output will be "15"

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPExcel How to get only 1 cell value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566638/phpexcel-how-to-get-only-1-cell-value)

Comment: No,I want to get the value based on column and row value, not by the cell reference

Comment: then you could split this task into two steps: iterate through A column and 1st row to find cells you need and combine them to use in the function to get 1 cell value

Comment: for example, 3.0 is at A5 and 5.0 at F1, so you need to combine F and 5 and get value by F5

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=INDEX(MyTable,MATCH(3,INDEX(MyTable,0,1),0),MATCH(5,INDEX(MyTable,1,0),0))
```

`MyTable` is a named range equal to A1:G15 in your example.
Match(**3** and Match(**5** are the two variables you wanted to work with. I expect you will feed them to the formula in some way. You can replace them with cell references and enter the numbers in the cells such designated.